# Open link to specific domain within an iFrame in a new window

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I need to be able to open a link to a specific URL that is within an iFrame; the link is generated by php and I can't change the source code, so I need to change the link in the iFrame dynamically, if possible.

What I'm doing is this: on a non-profit organization's site, I have an affiliate store (generated by php) displayed within an iFrame on a page in order to make it more styled with the rest of the site. The php store pulls products from an affiliate service; the link to the store.php is in the same domain as the main non-profit's site.

The problem is the final "Buy Now" link from a product opens the final destination e-commerce store within the iFrame, and as such the page is stuck in the iFrame and looks bad and one must scroll V and H to see it and check out.

The link I need to open in a new window always has the class "av_buy_now" I have access to the CSS file, which I can change. I have access to the PHP files, i.e. shop.php, but it doesn't appear that the final link is generated locally. I'm showing the iframe this way:

```
<iframe src="http://nonprofit.org/shop/mj/shop.php"></iframe>
```

Is it possible to use jQuery or Javascript to find the links to mydomain.com with that one class and add a new window attribute to them? Or is there a better way?  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Without some code I don't know the exact structure of your code, but I this could do the job. It requires jQuery to be in the iframe too.

```
$('iframe')[0].$('.av_buy_now').filter(function() {
    return $(this).attr('href').indexOf('mydomain.com') > -1;
}).attr('target', '_blank');
```

Comment: Hmm.. How would I include jQuery in the iFrame? I can include it in the html template that the iFrame displays; is that the way?

Answer (score 0):

You can change it if some how you can manage to execute this kind of code, changing class is little troublesome, of you got an id on it do something like this.

PAGE.html:

```
<button onclick="openinnewwin()">Get It</button>
<iframe src="test.html" id="ifrm"></iframe>
<script language="javascript">
function openinnewwin(){
ob=document.getElementById('ifrm');
if ( ob.contentDocument ) {
    ob.contentDocument.getElementById('a').target="_blank"; 
}else if ( ob.contentWindow ){
    ob.contentWindow.getElementById('a').target="_blank";   
}
}
</script>
```

test.html:

```
<a href="http://www.google.com" class="aaa" id="a">Hello</a>
```